# Standard resolution for all devices, without media queries?

Tags: cs6

I have a speed reading meter on my site that I want to open on all possible devices.

What is a good, standard size that will work for all devices, without using media queries?

Comment: Hi there! I have some trouble understanding what you need. Are you asking about the minimum size an image should have?

Comment: I think a 50px by 50px image fits the Apple Watch :)

Comment: "100%" would fit everything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking or are trying to achieve.

With that said, 320px would be the max-width you would want to use if you want it to work on all modern screen sizes.